# Can I pass the result of angular expression to Html helper function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a Html extension method called `Urlhash` which accept and return encrypted value of given data. Here I want to pass an angular expression as a parameter of this function i.e.:

```
<a href="@Html.Urlhash({{currentId}})">Go</a>
```

How can I achieve my goal using above code (`currentId` is variable in my angular control) or is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't. `AngularJS` is a *client-side* JS framework, but `@Html` is *server-side*.

If you need to call this method from JS you need to make an AJAX call to an action which returns the converted result.